# How to generate WSDL (WSDL 2.0) for a RESTfull webservice

Tags: web-services, rest, annotations, semantic-web, wsdl-2.0

i'm searching for a methode to generate a WSDL(WSDL2) webservice descriptor for my RESTfull webservice in php.

i know that RESTfull webservice doesn't need a description like SOAP, but i need the WSDL for REST WS to add a semantic annotation for the webservice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [tinyWSDL](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tinywsdl/) for this.

take a look [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/tinywsdl/wiki/creating/) to start with.
If you use XML Schema you can either add DOM Element or use tinyXMLSchema plugin (+ Apache XML Schema 2.1 libaray).

```
Types types = description.getTypes();
SchemaTypesExtensions extensions = (SchemaTypesExtensions)types.getComponentExtensions(WSDLPredefinedExtension.SCHEMA.URI);
Schema schema = extensions.newSchema();
```

// here you can either create a new Schema
    XmlSchema xmlSchema = (XmlSchema)schema.getSchema();

// or set already parsed one:
    schema.setSchema(xmlSchema)

In case you don't want to bother with Apache XML Shcema library you can always use DOM Element:

```
types.addExtensionElement(new QName("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema", "schema", "xs"), element)
```

Cheers,

D.

P.S. there is also WSDL 2.0 -> WADL converter in the sourcecode (not in the jar).